# Is there a way to stop Mail auto CC'ing yourself, when replying all ?

Tags: macos, mail.app

In OSX 10.11 mail app if you "Reply all" it automatically CC's yourself. This seems to only happen when using reply all, but not when using reply.

The setting under : mail > preferences > composing > automatically cc myself is disabled.

Is there a way to stop Mail auto CC'ing yourself, when replying all ?

Comment: I’d like to know as well if this was a usability oversight from the Mail developers. I would think so because in the closely related workflow of replying when you happened to be the last sender in a thread it replies to yourself rather than the other person in the thread which always slows things down having to reply all, move the other recipient’s mail to the To line, and delete my email from the To line.

Answer (score 1):

The preference is to keep a copy of an e-mail you originate or reply to one person or forward.  I don't see the point, since a copy goes into a Sent folder anyway.

Reply All means **All** people on the message, not just **some**.  If you don't want to keep a copy, just erase your name before sending.  Of course, there will still be a copy in your sent folder anyway.

Comment: Agreed it strange because IMAP will keep a copy in the sent folder. I know when using POP people used to CC or BCC themselves so they would have a copy across multiple devices. In OSX 10.10 using reply all will reply to all recipients, but not inlcude you (the sender)

Comment: That would be incorrect, and I don't recall any version (from 9.0 to Mojave) ever handling reply all incorrectly.